# install module snapshot python

Tags: python, wxpython

I am using wxPython to build the GUI for my application. I built the GUI using wxFormBuilder. But when bring the code into my python application, and launch it the window pops up then closes instantly. I am using the XRC for my GUI as well. I am given no error message in the console either while using PyDev with Eclipse.

Python code to launch GUI: http://pastebin.com/jBYWerd9

XRC code: http://pastebin.com/QVEcuX0i

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need

```
def main():
    app = VisualController(redirect=False)
    app.MainLoop() #you need this
    return #after calling Mainloop you will not get here until your main window is destroyed
```

Comment: With the addition of `def main():
    app = VisualController()
    app.MainLoop() #you need this
    return #after calling Mainloop you will not get here until your main window is destroyed` I still have the same issue where the frame at least comes up, but then closes itself.

Comment: try adding the `redirect=False` from my edit above and run it from the command line my guess is that you are getting an error and its closing too fast for you to see the error (tbh im not sure I havent messed much with the xrc stuff)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is two-fold. As Joran mentioned, you need to actually create an instance of your App class and call the MainLoop() method. The second piece is that you need to actually load the frame from the XRC file and Show it. Change your code to something like this:

```
import wx
from wx import xrc

class VisualController(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.res = xrc.XmlResource('data/GUI.xrc')
        frame = self.res.LoadFrame(None, "MyFrame1")
        frame.Show()
        return True

def main():
    app = VisualController(redirect=False)
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you don't load the frame and show it, then the app doesn't do anything and just exits when it finishes running the OnInit() method. Here are a few links on using XRC:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/11/wxpython-an-introduction-to-xrc/
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/XRCTutorial
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/UsingXmlResources